# Writing .d.ts file so I can share constants with JavaScript and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a node.js project that for historical reasons involves both TypeScript and JavaScript. I'd like to set up some project-wide constants that can be used in both languages. Obvious: write a `.js` file with the constants, and a `.d.ts` file that includes the types for TypeScript's use. But no: several hours of beating on the problem (and RTFMing) have gotten me nowhere.

Here's my first try at the constants file:

```
// constants.js
const MY_CONST_1 = 1;
exports.MY_CONST_1 = MY_CONST_1;
```

... and the JavaScript which uses it:

```
// consumer.js
let constants = require('./constants');
let one = constants.MY_CONST_1;
```

That works well, but when I try the obvious in TypeScript:

```
// consumer.ts
import * as constants from './constants';
let one: number = constants.MY_CONST_1;
```

Nope: `error TS2307: Cannot find module './constants'.` So, gotta write a `constants.d.ts` file, in the same directory as the `constants.js` file, right? Sounds easy, but a half dozen different attempts have yielded exactly zilch. No matter what I do, Typescript complains `error TS2306: File '/Users/griscom/Documents/Work/test/constants.d.ts' is not a module`.

So, what would a successful `constants.d.ts` file look like? Or, if I'd have to make changes in `constants.js` for it all to work, what would they be?

P.S. Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  }
}
```

(This seems like such a simple and obvious need; it's frustrating how opaque the process is.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Option 1: `allowJs`

Try using the compiler option `allowJs: true`. This will allow your original import from `./constants` to work even though it's a `.js` file, without the need to create a separate `.d.ts` file. TypeScript will understand inferrable types from the `.js` file, for example you will get type checking against `MY_CONST_1` as a number.

As you said in your comment this requires separating your source files from your output files, because it can't output a JS file at the same location as a JS source file.

## Option 2: `constants.d.ts` declaration file

Given your source file that looks like this:

```
// constants.js
export const MY_CONST_1 = 1;
```

You can write a `constants.d.ts` file that looks like this:

```
// constants.d.ts
export const MY_CONST_1: number;
```

Where you were off in your previous attempts is using the declaration `module`, which is used to declare types for external modules (like from `node_modules`). In this case simply putting the `constants.d.ts` file in the same directory as `constants.js` and using `export` will tell TS that it's a JS module that exports that value:

```
import { MY_CONST_1 } from "./constants";
import * as constants from "./constants";
```

**Something important to keep in mind** is that the `.d.ts` file is not checked against the `.js` file to ensure it's actually correct, that's on you. So if you make a change to the `.js` file you have to make sure to update the `.d.ts` file accordingly and correctly. A compile error or lack of compile error does not mean it's correct or not. This is one reason `allowJs` exists because it avoids such leaks.

Comment: Good idea, but then all the other JavaScript files in my project trigger errors: "Cannot write file XXXX because it would overwrite input file".

Comment: Yeah, you would need to separate your source files from your output files. JS source files will be copied with minimal transformation (just ES6 to ES5 syntax, for example).

Comment: Why not? Alternatively writing a `.d.ts` file should work, what have you tried?

Comment: This is a big, existing project, and the benefits of adding this feature would be outweighed by the complexities of changing the build process. In terms of `.d.ts` files, I've tried a number of examples I found on the web, but the compiler kept opaquely complaining.

Comment: I know the feeling, but in my experience it's usually more a mental hurdle than anything else. :) Can you post the `.d.ts` stuff you've tried in your question?

Comment: I added three examples that don't work. I'm guessing that the correct answer would take five lines of code and about three minutes, but I just can't get there.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Added an example using a declaration file

Comment: Thanks: that's perfect. (I edited out your comment about my file names; those were typos in composing the question, which I've now fixed.)

Answer (score 0):

```
export const MyConst =1;
```

Or

```
export class MyGroup {
    static MyConst: number
}
```

Generally stay clear of modules since that isnt compatible with the meaning of modules in inports. Instead use "namespace" which is very similar to a class with static members. Meaning you could probably do (on phone and cant try it out):

```
export namespace MyNamespace {
    export const MyConst = 1;
}
```

But lastly try avoid wrapping things in extra namespaces and classes etc since the import syntax is the module. Also it makes your code treeshakeable.

Comment: https://michelenasti.com/2019/01/23/is-typescript-namespace-feature-deprecated.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option: using an [import for side effects only](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only). Indeed, your constants are global, i.e. not defined in a module due to the missing `export` keyword:

`import './constants';`

*To be used in combination with the `allowJs` compiler option mentionned in an another response.*